# npx create-react-app client gives this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\priyesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-09T13_17_00_252Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client/ from C:\work\blog
Done.
```

Comment: i am using node version 16

Comment: is git installed on your system (try `git --v`)? can you try `yarn create react-app my-app`?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem while also trying node 16.

Comment: @PriyeshRanjan, did you figure out a solution by chance?

Answer (score 2):

This error simply shows difference between version of global packages..update windows, npm, node remove cached memory in node. sometime reconnect to internet will  help in this error..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with node 16.0.0 - with current latest 16.13.2 it works